# Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'arr' of undefined(…) TypeError: Cannot read property 'arr' of undefined

Tags: angular, angularfire2

Hi I'm working on make multiple form validation and I got an eror
'TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined '

And I have no idea what should I do.
Here is my

app.component.ts

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable, FirebaseObjectObservable } from 'angularfire2';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/count';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  public employees: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  public updateForm: FormGroup;
  public formArray = new FormArray([]);
  employeesCount: number;
  angular: any;

  constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.employees = af.database.list('/employees');
  }
  addEmployee( firstname: string, lastname:string, age:number , sex: string) {
    this.employees.push({ firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, age: age, sex:sex});
  }
  updateEmployee(key: string, firstname: string, lastname:string, age:number , sex: string) {
    this.employees.update(key, { firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, age: age, sex:sex } );
  }
  deleteEmployee(key: string) {    
    this.employees.remove(key); 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.angular.forEach(this.employees, function(value, key) {
      this.formArray.push(
        new FormGroup({firstname: new FormControl([Validators.required])})
      );
      console.log(value);
    });
    this.updateForm = new FormGroup(
      {firstname: new FormControl([Validators.required])}
      );

  }
}
```

The above problem is solved by `this.employees.forEach(function(employee){...})`

I have another problem at the same code it tell **`Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'arr' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: WebSocket.addEventListener:message ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'arr' of undefined(…) TypeError: Cannot read property 'arr' of undefined`**

how hard I try it not work I dont know why ?

```css
export class AppComponent {
  public employees: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
  public updateForm: FormGroup;
  public arr = new FormArray([]);

  constructor(af: AngularFire) {
    this.employees = af.database.list('/employees');
  }
  addEmployee( firstname: string, lastname:string, age:number , sex: string) {
    this.employees.push({ firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, age: age, sex:sex});
  }
  updateEmployee(key: string, firstname: string, lastname:string, age:number , sex: string) {
    this.employees.update(key, { firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, age: age, sex:sex } );
  }
  deleteEmployee(key: string) {    
    this.employees.remove(key); 
  }

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.employees.forEach(function(e) {
      this.arr.push(new FormGroup({firstname: new FormControl([Validators.required])}));
      console.log(this.arr);
    });

  }
```

Comment: You never actually assign `angular` a value, you need to give it some sort of array it can parse through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call `this.employees.forEach()`. It appears that you're trying to use the AngularJS (version 1) method `angular.forEach()` which is not necessary in Angular 2.

The field `angular` can be removed since it's not used for anything.

Comment: It would just be `this.employees.forEach(function(employee){...})`.

Comment: I have another problem

Comment: `this` changes scope within `forEach()` and `this.arr` is not defined within that scope. You should capture the component instance before entering the `forEach()` block. Make the first line of `ngOnInit()` something like this: `let appComponent = this;` and then call `appComponent.arr.push()`.

Answer (score 0):

It llok like you never assigned a value to your angular property as well as make sure the angular property value should be array. I think over object it does not work

[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach][1]